# Add subdomain index page in .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I am using zend framework and i have .htaccess file in web directory which is redirect to public/index.php .
My web directory structure is given below:

```
webroot/
   application/
      controllers/
      views/
         scripts/
   library/
   public/
     index.php     
   tests/
   .htaccess
```

My .htaccess code is given below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

After that i create a subdomain i.e "sub.mydomain.com" .

then my webroot directory given below:

```
webroot/
       sub/
       application/
          controllers/
          views/
             scripts/
       library/
       public/
         index.php     
       tests/
       .htaccess
```

when i open then error msg come :

```
The requested URL /public/sub/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

when i delete above htaccess file code then my subdomain sub.mydomain.com is open .
I want to change my code of htaccess file. In which both my domaine or subdomain is run....please help me...

Comment: We'll need more information on your file structure and where your main domain and sub-domain are each pointing to (the folder). Your .htaccess file for the main domain should not affect your sub-domain at all unless their directories overlap.

Comment: I explaine my question more please suggest me what can i do ?

Comment: Create a .htaccess in your sub domain to over write main domain .htaccess

Comment: Please share code with me.... :)